# Fourier transform of sin, cos, and exponential function

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I am using this definitions of Fourier transform. Should there be 1/2\pi factor in the inverse one?

\begin{equation}
    G(\omega) = \mathcal{F}[g(t)] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t) e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d} t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    g(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[G(\omega)] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}G(\omega) e^{i \omega t} \mathrm{d} \omega
\end{equation}

Why the sum of the FTs of sin and cos is not equal to the FT of the exponential according to Euler's equation? It should be the real and the imaginary part, right?

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}[e^{i \omega_0 t}] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i \omega_0 t} e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d} t = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i t (\omega_0 - \omega)} \mathrm{d} t= \mathrm{d}elta(\omega_0 - \omega) = \delta(\omega - \omega_0)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \mathcal{F}[\cos(\omega_0 t)] &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\omega_0 t) e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d} t  = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i t\omega_0} + e^{-i t \omega_0}}{2} e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d} t  =\\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i t(\omega - \omega_0)} \mathrm{d} t +  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i t(\omega + \omega_0)} \mathrm{d} t  \right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \delta (\omega - \omega_0) + \delta (\omega + \omega_0) \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \mathcal{F}[\sin(\omega_0 t)] &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(\omega_0 t) e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d} t  = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i t\omega_0} - e^{-i t \omega_0}}{2i} e^{-i \omega t} \mathrm{d} t  =\\
    &= \frac{1}{2i} \left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i t(\omega - \omega_0)} \mathrm{d} t -  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i t(\omega + \omega_0)} \mathrm{d} t  \right] = \frac{1}{2i} \left[ \delta (\omega - \omega_0) - \delta (\omega + \omega_0) \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thank you

**Edit:**

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F} [\delta (t-a)] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta (t-a) e^{- i \omega t}  \mathrm{d}t = e^{-i \omega a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}^{-1} [e^{-i \omega a}] = \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i \omega a} e^{i \omega t} \mathrm{d}\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i \omega (t-a)} \mathrm{d}\nu= \frac{1}{2\pi}  \delta(t-a)
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, there is a factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ missing.

Comment: Thank you. And what about the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ before both, direct and inverse transformation? When there is the factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ only in the inverse FT, there is a problem with FT in two lines I added to the question.

Comment: That's also a possibility. You can also put the factor in the exponent of the exponential function. There are several ways to define the Fourier transform.

Comment: But why where is the mistake then, please?

Comment: There is no mistake. You have proven that $\mathcal{F}[e^{i\omega_0 t}] = \mathcal{F}[\cos(\omega_0 t)] + i\mathcal{F}[\sin(\omega_0 t)]$, which is just linearity of the Fourier transform. I don't see any problem.

Comment: Thank you very much